# How to fix mingw32/bin/ld.exe: cannot open output file sample input1.exe: Permission denied error in C?

Tags: c, eclipse, compiler-errors

When I compile a C program in Eclipse IDE it gives the below error.

> mingw32/bin/ld.exe: cannot open output file sample input1.exe:
> Permission denied

How to fix this?